# Зависает Unity, возможная проблема - бесконечный цикл, не могу решить

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся c такой проблемой - зависает Unity при запуске определённого скрипта. Подозреваю, что в этом виноват бесконечный цикл. Несколько раз проверил условие, но ошибок не нашёл. Ошибка расположена в chankGenerate(). Буду признателен за любую помощь.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGenerate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objects;
    float corX, corY;
    int corXint, corYint;
    bool[,] matrixPL, matrixMN;

    void Start()
    {
        matrixPL = new bool[5, 5];
        matrixMN = new bool[5, 5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                matrixPL[i, j] = false;
                matrixMN[i, j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        corX = GameObject.Find("Camera2D").GetComponent<Transform>().position.x;
        corY = GameObject.Find("Camera2D").GetComponent<Transform>().position.y;

        corXint = (int) Mathf.Round(corX);
        corYint = (int) Mathf.Round(corY);

        if (corXint >= 0)
        {
            corXint = corXint / 40 + 1;
        }

        else
        {
            corXint = (corXint + 1) / 40 - 1;
        }

        corYint = (corYint / 40) * (-1);

        chankGenerate(corXint, corYint);
    }

    void chankGenerate(int x, int y)
    {

        if (x > 0 && !matrixPL[x, y])
        {
            matrixPL[x, y] = true;

            for (int i = (x - 1) * 40; i < x * 40; x += 4)
            {
                for (int j = y * (-40); j > (y + 1) * (-40); y -= 4)
                    {
//Если не убрать код ниже (3 строки), то Unity зависает
                        int rand1 = Random.Range(-2, 2);
                        int rand2 = Random.Range(-2, 2);
                        Instantiate(objects[0], new Vector3(i + rand1, j + rand2, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(0, 360)));
                    }
                }
            }

        if (x < 0 && !matrixMN[x * (-1), y])
        {
            matrixMN[x, y] = true;

            for (int i = x * (-40); i < (x - 1) * 40; x += 4)
            {
                for (int j = y * (-40); j > (y + 1) * (-40); y -= 4)
                {
                    int rand1 = Random.Range(-2, 2);
                    int rand2 = Random.Range(-2, 2);
                    Instantiate(objects[0], new Vector3(i + rand1, j + rand2, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(0, 360)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Скажите, а в `Start` у массивов matrixPL, matrixMN Вы меняете только  [0,0] - так и задумано?

Comment: Да и условия циклов в `chankGenerate` слишком уж странные.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский спасибо, я этого не заметил "меняете только [0,0]"

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский эти условия отрисовывают чанки. Чанк 1-1 - это от 0 до 39 по оси Х и от - 40 до -79 по оси У. Всё с шагом в 4 клетки.

Comment: `for (int i = (x - 1) * 40; i < x * 40; x += 4)` - вы почему-то вместо счетчика `i` меняете переменную `x`. Пожалуйста, не надо так делать. У вас нарушается логика и на всех итерациях цикла счетчик имеет одно и то же значение, и возможно, что это и есть причина вашего бага.

Comment: @trollingchar спасибо больше, не заметил. Больше так не буду)